# Junction table vs linking table vs joining table vs bridging table

Tags: database, database-design, naming-conventions

I was recently trying to figure out how to set up a many-to-many relationship in my database. In the multitude of websites (such as [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab)) I've visited, they each seemed to use different terms to refer to the same thing, a table which contains the IDs from two separate tables to be used to define relationships. For example, a book can have many authors and an author can have many books, the linking/bridging/joining/juntion table would look like:

```
+------------+-----------+
|  book_id   | author_id |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          |        1  |
| 2          |        2  |
| 3          |        3  |  
| 3          |        5  |  
| 4          |        5  |  
+------------+-----------+
```

What is the accepted term for such a table, or are all terms acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Junction Table.

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity):

> An associative (or junction) table maps two or more tables together by referencing the primary keys of each data table. In effect, it contains a number of foreign keys, each in a many-to-one relationship from the junction table to the individual data tables. The PK of the associative table is typically composed of the FK columns themselves.